# I can't land on the spring after the checkpoint in "Two if By"

Tags: runner2

What should happen is this:

What happens instead is this:

[image]

I hold the spring button the entire time, but no matter how I time the trampoline jump I never manage the spring jump. What gives?

Comment: I only managed this *twice* through video recording software induced delays, which is completely random

Answer (score 2):

I've tried and tried and tried some more, but, after having it work successfully on my first attempt (followed by dying immediately after), I can't get it to work again. It's likely that it could be bugged (not working as designed post-Checkpoint), but I did manage to find a way to get past it and still get those gold pieces!

You can, with some careful timing, glide over *both* the trampoline and the goomba-ish guy. Just jump at the last possible second, hold the jump button to glide, and hold up when you hit the springboard.

If you're really worried about the points you missed by skipping the trampoline, you can take the "Harder" path just past this point. It's incredibly easy, and you should be able to make up the points in no time.

Comment: +1 Jumping over both of them in a single long jump is the way to go.